# how could I pass a collection of the arguments that a function needed?

Tags: python

For example, I have a function:

```
def foo(a, b, c):
    pass
```

Now I have  a dict:
`d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}`
I have to write something like:
`foo(d['a'], d['b'], d['c'])`
I'd like to know, could I just pass a collection of the arguments(like `d`) to the function?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure, you can pass a dict as `kwargs`:

```
def foo(a, b, c):
    print a, b, c

d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
foo(**d)
```

Output:

```
1 2 3
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the [dictionary unpacking operator (`**`)](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.6/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

```
foo(**d)
```

Answer (score 3):

`foo(**d)` should work.

See http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists